# nmcli signal for current connection

Tags: network-manager

I'm looking for a way to get the signal for the current connection using nmcli. I know that I could parse the result of `nmcli dev wifi list` but it would be great to avoid this step. I searched in the documentation and the closest command I found is `nmcli connection show "My SSID"` but unfortunately there's nothing in the results about the signal.

Is there a more efficient way to get the signal of the current connection ?

Thanks

Comment: The capabilities seem to change from release to release, but so far I haven't found anything better than parsing the output - however you *can* be selective about what fields you include e.g. `nmcli -f ACTIVE,SIGNAL dev wifi list | awk '$1=="yes" {print $2}'`